VBA: Extract and Assign Recipients from Product Titles using Reference Keywords
I'm working on a project where I need to extract the intended recipients from product titles based on keywords provided in a reference sheet. The results are then written into the "Recipient From Title" column of the "PRODUCTS" sheet.
Here's what I am working with:
Scenario:
Sheet "PRODUCTS": Contains product details, including a column for "Product Title" that needs to be matched to a recipient category.
Sheet "REFERENCE": Contains a list of product titles in column A and the intended recipient(s) in column B.
The goal is to fill in the "Recipient From Title" column in the "PRODUCTS" sheet by matching phrases in the product title against a reference list and then assigning the correct recipients. If a title matches multiple keywords, they should be concatenated and separated by a semicolon ;.
sample of both sheets given below
ProductSheet (Data to be filled)

Reference sheet (Used for Lookup)

Below is my attempt at the code that aims to iterate through each product in the "PRODUCTS" sheet, find keywords from the "REFERENCE" sheet, and fill in the appropriate recipients:
Sub FillRecipientFromTitle()
    Dim wsProducts As Worksheet, wsReference As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowProducts As Long, LastRowReference As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim title As String, recipient As String
    
    ' Set worksheets
    Set wsProducts = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PRODUCTS")
    Set wsReference = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REFERENCE")
    
    ' Get last rows for both sheets
    LastRowProducts = wsProducts.Cells(wsProducts.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowReference = wsReference.Cells(wsReference.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through each product row
    For i = 2 To LastRowProducts
        title = LCase(wsProducts.Cells(i, 1).Value) ' Product Title in Column A of PRODUCTS
        recipient = ""
        
        ' Loop through reference list to find a match
        For j = 2 To LastRowReference
            If InStr(1, title, LCase(wsReference.Cells(j, 1).Value)) > 0 Then
                If recipient = "" Then
                    recipient = wsReference.Cells(j, 2).Value
                ElseIf InStr(1, recipient, wsReference.Cells(j, 2).Value) = 0 Then
                    recipient = recipient & ";" & wsReference.Cells(j, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        
        ' Write Recipient to PRODUCTS Sheet Column B
        wsProducts.Cells(i, 2).Value = recipient
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Data has been processed successfully!"
End Subp


Issues I'm Facing:

This approach works, but it's very slow with larger datasets (500+ rows in the product sheet as the sheet can scale up to even 100k rows). It takes a significant amount of time to complete due to the nested loops.
-Sometimes, it's matching incorrectly, especially if there are partial matches (e.g., "Mum" in "Grandmum"). Also if the product title contains only “Daughter” I would like the recipient output to be “Daughter” (As set in the reference)
I would not want a product containing the phrase “God Daughter” To be output as “Daughter” as this should only fall under “Godchild”

I am happy to provide the excel sheet for whoever wants to take a look
Excel

Ideally your reference list only has one item per row in the first column, and you sort it in order of descending length.  As you make a match, remove that match from the title (using Replace for example) so you don't later make another partial match - eg matching and removing "god daughter" prevents a later match on "daughter"

@TimWilliams Replace speeds down.

I guess to replace two-word keys by a single-word one (god_daughter) first. Split every title into words. Use the reference dictionary.

PS your reference list is missing "Grandma"

Follow rotabor's recommendation about splitting up your table.  Then write everything into arrays and process them, finishing by writing the values to an array and then writing the array back to Excel.  This approach is vastly faster than iterating through the data in Excel.  You'll end up with more code, but it will execute FAST.

Ideally your reference list only has one item per row in the first column, and you sort it in order of descending length. See below for how this restructuring might be done dynamically using your existing layout.
After you make a match, remove that match from title (using Replace for example) so you don't later make another partial match - eg matching and removing "god daughter" prevents a later match on "daughter".
You can use a regexp object instead of Instr to make sure your test respects word boundaries eg "son" doesn't match on "personalized".
Try this out.  In my tests this processed 12k products in just over 3 sec.
Sub FillRecipientFromTitle()
    Dim wsProducts As Worksheet, wsReference As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowProducts As Long, LastRowReference As Long, term As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, arr, el, col As Collection, t
    Dim title As String, data, refs, newRefs, newRefRows As Long
    
    Set wsProducts = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PRODUCTS")
    Set wsReference = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REFERENCE")
    t = Timer
    
    'get an array of all of the reference data
    refs = wsReference.Range("A2:B" & LastRow(wsReference, "A")).Value
    'Create a new array with one row per term to match on,
    '  and sort it descending by length
    ReDim newRefs(1 To 5 * UBound(refs, 1), 1 To 2) 'should be large enough...
    i = 0
    For r = 1 To UBound(refs, 1)
        arr = Split(refs(r, 1), ",") 'split on comma
        For Each el In arr           'add each item to the new array
            i = i + 1
            newRefs(i, 1) = LCase(Trim(el))
            newRefs(i, 2) = refs(r, 2)
        Next el
    Next r
    newRefRows = i
    Debug.Print Timer - t, "New reference array has " & newRefRows & " entries"
    SortByLength newRefs, 1 'sort descending by length of first column value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'get all product data as array
    data = wsProducts.Range("A2:A" & LastRow(wsProducts, "A")).Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then Debug.Print Timer - t, "Checking", i
        title = LCase(data(i, 1))
        recipient = ""
        Set col = New Collection
        ' Loop through sorted reference array to look for match
        For j = 1 To newRefRows
            term = newRefs(j, 1)
            If WordMatch(title, term) Then
                On Error Resume Next 'ignore any duplicate key error
                col.Add newRefs(j, 2), newRefs(j, 2)
                On Error GoTo 0
                'remove the matched term so it won't match later
                ' eg match on "God Daughter" won't also match "Daughter"
                title = Replace(title, term, "", 1, compare:=vbTextCompare)
            End If
        Next j
        data(i, 1) = ColToList(col) 'recipient(s)
    Next i
    
    'populate recipients to col B
    wsProducts.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(data, 1)).Value = data
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer - t, "Done"
    MsgBox "Data has been processed successfully!"
End Sub

'See if `term` is in the string `txt` accounting for word boundaries
'  So (eg) "son" does not return True if tested against "personalized"
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Function WordMatch(txt As String, term As String) As Boolean
    Static re As Object   'faster if you don't create a new object for each call...
    If re Is Nothing Then
        Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        re.ignorecase = True
    End If
    re.Pattern = "\b" & term & "\b" 'check word boundaries
    WordMatch = re.Test(txt)
End Function

Function LastRow(ws As Worksheet, colRef As String) As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, colRef).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

'concatenate collection items to a list
Function ColToList(col As Collection) As String
    Dim i As Long, s As String, sep As String
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        ColToList = ColToList & sep & col(i)
        sep = ";"
    Next i
End Function

'Sort an array (in place) by item length (descending) using bubble sort algorithm
Sub SortByLength(data, colIndex As Long)

    Dim FirstC As Integer, LastC As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    Dim tmp
    FirstC = LBound(data, 2)
    LastC = UBound(data, 2)
    
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            'compare data length in specified column
            If Len(data(i, colIndex)) < Len(data(j, colIndex)) Then
                'swap rows
                For c = FirstC To LastC
                    tmp = data(j, c)
                    data(j, c) = data(i, c)
                    data(i, c) = tmp
                Next c
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


